# jQuery readonly slider - how to do?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-ui-slider

How can I have a jQuery slider that is readonly? One that would display a value but the user wouldn't be allowed to move it?

Thanks

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The documentation says there's a `.slider('disable')` function - not sure what that actually does to the slider element itself, but that may be an option for you.

[Documentation here](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Slider#method-disable)

Comment: This is making the slider disappear (not being rendered).

Comment: Then I suppose the easiest way to do it would be to position a transparent element on top of the slider (thus preventing the user from moving it manually) and control its position using the .value attribute.

Comment: I'm using jquery-ui-1.9.2 and `.slider("disable")` works like a charm. It decreases the transparency and disables dragability.

Comment: Any way to keep the transparency as it is but disable dragability at the same time?

Comment: @ThomasSebastian try to add `$(".ui-slider-disabled.ui-state-disabled").removeClass("ui-state-disabled");` after you call it.

Answer (score 7):

I tried all suggested. Only this works:

```
$('#mySlider').slider({ disabled: true });
```

Answer (score 6):

Disabling it makes it transparent. If you want it to look like a normal slider, you can override slide handler to return false:

```
    $("#mySlider").on("slide", function (event, ui) { return false; });
```

Comment: This does the job.

Answer (score 3):

I have got the same issue that the slider disappears if I use directly $('#mySlider').slider( 'disable' );. I have loaded the slider fisrt..then disabled it. Though it is not a good way, but it works for me.

```
$('#mySlider').slider(
            {
                range: "min",
                min: 0,
                max: 100,                
                value: $("span", this).text(), 

                }

            });
$('#mySlider').slider( 'disable');
```

Answer (score 1):

You would simply have to do this:

```
$('#mySlider').slider( 'disable' );
```

Comment: This is making the slider disappear (not being rendered).

Answer (score 0):

`$("#slider").slider("disable")` works fine, however reenabling doesn't work `$("#slider").slider("enable")`

Answer (score -1):

I had a client request for this today. Its probably a good idea to do this as a best practice and prevent string input.

Since the slider sets the value in an <input> tag, you can make it "[readonly](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#adef-readonly)".

```
<p>
  <label for="amount">Price range:</label>
  <input type="text" id="amount" style="border: 0; color: #f6931f; font-weight: bold;" readonly />
</p>

<div id="slider-range"></div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gyrostu/4KWaX/)

Comment: This is not what the OP asked for.  He wanted the slider to be disabled, which is not what your example shows.